# emacs R mode ESS

Tags: emacs, r, mode

I can run the R interpreter through emacs. However, I am looking for the R mode for writing scripts that would perform syntax highlighting, autocompletion and so forth (let me know if there are other features you would recommend as well).

For example, I have opened up an R script (with file extension `.R`) but the mode says `fundamental`, how would I get an `R mode` to be used when I open R scripts?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and emacs 24.3, let me know if you need any more information and thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `.emacs` file do you have the line `(setq-default ess-dialect "R")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it from [this primer](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~thocking/primer.html#sec-2.2), the mode in question is `R-mode`. You can confirm this by visiting a file of R code and doing `M-x R-mode`; if your buffer is fontified (i.e., syntax-highlighted), you know this is the mode you want to use for your R files.

To automatically set this major mode when visiting files of R code, add the following to your Emacs init file (`~/.emacs`, `/.emacs.el`, `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, &c.):

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.R$" . R-mode))
```

Please note that I haven't actually had cause to use ESS myself, so may be mistaken in the mode name for R source. That said, the pattern will hold true for whatever mode you need to invoke; if you can find out the name of the mode you need, substituting it for `R-mode` in the `(add-to-list)` call will produce the desired effect.